# Who empowered the other Grails that appear at the end of Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade, holy-grail

After making it past the three tests, "Breath of God", "Name of God" and "Leap of Faith", Indiana enters a small room with an old bent knight sitting and reading a Bible, a large table of gold grails behind him.

All but one of those grails, the Holy Grail, give whovever drinks of them death.

Donovan drinks out of one of them, and he turns into a skeleton. Who put the power to immediately kill into those grails?

Comment: Well, who installed the beheading saws and abyss traps and all? There seems to be a common homicidal theme there.

Comment: Maybe it was the same force that put the power to immediately kill into the Ark of Covenant. Whatever power that was behind it seemed to like rules that kill people who break them, a lot.

Comment: God, I guess? Or George Lucas.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But why would God put a power into a whole ton of grails that would kill whoever drank of them? What if they lost one?

Comment: @leftaroundabout That would be the Brotherhood of the Cruciform Sword, or their original organization, according to the Ultimate Guide published some years back.

Comment: The power need not be in the false grails. It could be in the water or the room or it could be something like the Holy Spirit that is everywhere and acts when certain situations arise. For that matter, it’s not necessary for there to be power in the true grail either.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter What if God lost a cup? I suspect that either omnisicence, omnipotence, or both, would probably prevent that from happening.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's not what I meant. I meant what if some greedy person stole one of those killing grails out of a caravan going to supply that room, and then they lost it and it was found by some innocent person.

Comment: I had a look at the film's novelization (based on a slightly earlier version of the screenplay) and it reads that when Indy selects the true Grail, he more or less is given a sign that it's the right one via some supernatural power. Since said supernatural power falls in line with the novel's rendition of the Grail Legend and that it clearly IS the Holy Grail, we can *presume* that it's God doing the "empowering". A point in the movie and novelization (and Arthurian legend etc) re: the Grail Quest is that it's more about purity of faith rather than the cup itself.

Comment: The novelization also mentions that the reason the Grail Knight stayed alive for so long is that he had to drink from the Grail *every day* and that on occasion his faith had wavered and he didn't drink from it, causing him to age a year or so for every day he didn't drink. The water itself isn't mentioned as being anything more than water in the novelization, nor in the Ultimate Guide which has a neat cross-section view of the Grail Temple and merely says the water comes from an ancient spring adjacent to the cave where the Grail Knight has been sitting and reading for centuries.

Comment: @CaptainKirk again, if God knows everything and can do everything, then presumably that was part of the plan all along. Isn’t religion fun?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - that's the difference between faith and religion for you. The problems show up immediately when someone confuses one for the other... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ['Brotherhood of the Cruciform Sword'](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Brotherhood_of_the_Cruciform_Sword) (the organisation which the titular three brothers founded and belonged) had access to Celtic magics, courtesy of their possession of the *Book of the Spells of Merlin* (or possibly access to the man himself), according to the [Grail Diary](https://archive.org/details/INDIANA_JONES_THE_LAST_CRUSADE_GRAIL_DIARY/page/n65/mode/2up) book that came with the video game [*Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade: The Graphic Adventure*](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Last_Crusade:_The_Graphic_Adventure).

The Brotherhood presumably used these magics to empower the Great Seal as well as the fake grails.

[image]